# Interesting Issue with Silverlight Datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Folks,

I'm having an interesting issue with Silverlight DataGrid data binding. It may be b/c I'm not binding the data source properly. Here's the object & the observable collection

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for all model elements
/// </summary>
public interface IBaseModel
{

}


/// <summary>
/// Employee model
/// </summary>
public class EmployeeModel : IBaseModel
{       

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + LastName;
    }
}


// The observable collection is loaded and bound in the user control
public partial class EmployeeMasterDetailsWindow : UserControl
{
    public EmployeeMasterDetailsWindow()
    {

        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ObservableCollection<IBaseModel> k = new ObservableCollection<IBaseModel>() 
                {new EmployeeModel(){FirstName="Frodo", 
                               LastName=" Baggins"}, 
                new EmployeeModel(){FirstName="Pippin", 
                               LastName="Thomas"}, 
                new EmployeeModel(){FirstName="John", 
                               LastName="Doe"}, 
                new EmployeeModel(){FirstName="Tim", 
                               LastName="Kiriev"}}; 

            dataGrid1.DataContext = k;
            CustomersListBox.DataContext = k;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

    }
}



//here's the XAML
<UserControl x:Class="AdventureWorksManagement.UI.EmployeeMasterDetailsWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="379" d:DesignWidth="516"
         xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit">


<UserControl.Resources>       

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <TextBlock Text=" " />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="371" Width="595">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="312*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="283*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <sdk:DataGrid Height="325" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="271" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerTemplate}">

    </sdk:DataGrid>
           <ListBox x:Name="CustomersListBox"
             Margin="10,10,10,11"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

The Listbox shows all the of the employees, but the DataGrid doesn't. I don't even see the DataGrid. I see this error message in the output window:

> 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[AdventureWorksManagement.Model.IBaseModel]'
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[AdventureWorksManagement.Model.IBaseModel]'
>   (HashCode=54025633).
>   BindingExpression: Path='FirstName'
>   DataItem='System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[AdventureWorksManagement.Model.IBaseModel]'
>   (HashCode=54025633); target element is
>   'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Text'
>   (type 'System.String')..

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does the listbox show FirstName + LastName instead of what you have declared in CustomerTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making it an `ObservableCollection<IBaseModel>` you are effectively casting all the child objects to IBaseModel, which has no members.

In this instance make it an `ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel>`.

Comment: But how come the ListBox control displays the data in ObservableCollection<IBaseModel> w/o casting?

Comment: @dormantroot: Listbox will use ToString() by default as it will cast each entry to an Object first if no other binding is specified. ToString() is virtual on Object, so is found correctly in your class.